# SwiftUI - How to make both parent and child views accessible to voiceover Accessibility

Tags: ios, swiftui, accessibility

I want accessibility to be in the way that first the parent view is read by voice over and then the child views are read individually. Trying the following code but it is not working as expected. It just reads the child views individually not the parent view. Also tried with `.combine` but it just reads the parent view only.
For eg:

```
    public var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Image("apple")
        Text("Text 1")
            .accessibilityLabel("Text 1")
        Text("Text 2")
            .accessibilityLabel("Text 2")
    }
    .accessibilityElement(children: .contain)
    .accessibilityLabel("Container view")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function of the `.contain` is described below. *(you can do ⌥ + click to see the descriptions in Xcode.)*

*Any child accessibility elements become children of the new accessibility element.*

So, `.contain` will first announce the accessibility label of `Container view` first and will announce the child items for each time. So you'll have an announcement like this:

`Container View, Image`
`Container View, Text 1`
`Container View, Text 2`

So, to achieve your intention, you can first remove the `.accessibilityElement(children: .contain)` because you don't need to combine or add a common announcement to children.

You can simply add a label to the first item, like below.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Image(systemName: "apple.logo")
            .accessibilityLabel("Container view")
        Text("Text 1")
            .accessibilityLabel("Text 1")
        Text("Text 2")
            .accessibilityLabel("Text 2")
    }
}
```

Also, a better practice might be using a `Group{ }` container to define an accessibility announcement.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I use to solve the problem is to create a ZStack with the clear Color, which serves as an accessibility container, and desired content "placed" on top of it.

```
public var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.clear
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .accessibilityElement()
            .accessibilityLabel("Container view")
        VStack {
            Image("apple")
            Text("Text 1")
                .accessibilityLabel("Text 1")
            Text("Text 2")
                .accessibilityLabel("Text 2")
        }
    }
    .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: true)
    .accessibilityElement(children: .contain)
}
```

Fixed size is provided to make the ZStack have exactly required sizes to place all content inside itself, and not use all available space as Color.clear would intend to do.

Additionally, you can provide `.accessibilitySortPriority(_:)` to decide what reading order Voice Over should follow.